# transform an array of objects into an array of objects with a different format

Tags: javascript

There is a use case whereby `data` needs to be transformed into `result` for the purpose of displaying the data in the UI in a pivoted format.  In `result` the numbered keys are the month numbers and their values are the quantity for that month.

```
const data = [
            { date: '10/1/2021', quantity: 47 },
            { date: '11/1/2021', quantity: 58 },
            { date: '12/1/2021', quantity: 96 },
            { date: '1/1/2022', quantity: 88 },
            { date: '2/1/2022', quantity: 90 },
        ];

const result = [
            { year: 2021, 10: 47, 11: 58, 12: 96 },
            { year: 2022, 1: 88, 2: 90 }
        ];
```

So far I have created `intermediate` but don't know how to get that into the final `result` format in a concise manner.  ES6 solutions are preferred.

```js
const data = [
    { date: '10/1/2021', quantity: 47 },
    { date: '11/1/2021', quantity: 58 },
    { date: '12/1/2021', quantity: 96 },
    { date: '1/1/2022', quantity: 88 },
    { date: '2/1/2022', quantity: 90 },
];

const intermediate = data.map(o => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const [month, day, year] = o.date.split('/');    // destructuring assignment
    return { year: year, [month]: o.quantity }
});

console.log(intermediate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to get from `intermediate` to `result`:

```js
const data = [
    { date: '10/1/2021', quantity: 47 },
    { date: '11/1/2021', quantity: 58 },
    { date: '12/1/2021', quantity: 96 },
    { date: '1/1/2022', quantity: 88 },
    { date: '2/1/2022', quantity: 90 },
];

const intermediate = data.map(o => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const [month, day, year] = o.date.split('/');    // destructuring assignment
    return { year: year, [month]: o.quantity }
});

let years = [...new Set(intermediate.map(o => o.year))];
let accumulator = Object.assign({}, ...years.map(year => ({[year]: {}})));

intermediate.forEach(o => {
    accumulator[o.year] = { ...accumulator[o.year], ...o };
});

const result = Object.values(accumulator);
console.log(result);
```

But the above contained more individual steps than necessary.  Ended up doing this -

```js
const data = [
    { date: '10/1/2021', quantity: 47 },
    { date: '11/1/2021', quantity: 58 },
    { date: '12/1/2021', quantity: 96 },
    { date: '1/1/2022', quantity: 88 },
    { date: '2/1/2022', quantity: 90 },
];

accumulator = {};

data.forEach(o => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const [month, day, year] = o.date.split('/');    // destructuring assignment
    accumulator[year] = { ...accumulator[year], year: year, [month]: o.quantity };
});

const result = Object.values(accumulator);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** from `intermediate` to `result`

```js
const intermediate = [
  { '10': 47, 'year': '2021' },
  { '11': 58, 'year': '2021' },
  { '12': 96, 'year': '2021' },
  { '1': 88, 'year': '2022' },
  { '2': 90, 'year': '2022' }
]

const yearDataMap = {}
intermediate.forEach(dto => {
  const storageObj = {} // temp store object

  Object.entries(dto).forEach(([key, value]) => { // destructure object props
    if(key === 'year') {
      storageObj['year'] = value
    }else {
      storageObj['month'] = key
      storageObj['quantity'] = value
    }
  })

  const {year, month, quantity} = storageObj 

  if (!yearDataMap[year]){ // if no entries with this year preset it with year record
    yearDataMap[year] = { year } // same as = { year: year }
  }

  yearDataMap[year][month] = quantity
})

const yearsArr = Object.values(yearDataMap)

console.log(yearsArr)
```

From `given` to `result`:

```js
const data = [
  { date: '10/1/2021', quantity: 47 },
  { date: '11/1/2021', quantity: 58 },
  { date: '12/1/2021', quantity: 96 },
  { date: '1/1/2022', quantity: 88 },
  { date: '2/1/2022', quantity: 90 },
];

const yearDataMap = {} // map to store dates by year

data.forEach(dto => {
  const {date, quantity} = dto
  const [month, day, year] = date.split('/')

  if (!yearDataMap[year]){ // if no entries with this year preset it with year record
    yearDataMap[year] = { year } // same as = { year: year }
  }

  yearDataMap[year][month] = quantity // adding quantity  by month
})

const yearDataArr = Object.values(yearDataMap) // get rid of map and get the `result`

console.log(yearDataArr)
```

Comment: Great comments to explain what the commented lines are doing!  My original code is similar to what you posted.  The `intermediate` approach is an attempt to refactor and shorten up the logic necessary to get to `result`.

Comment: @knot22, If you run a code snippet you'll get the `result` . Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Your code snippet does yield the correct output.  However, I'm looking for how to get from `intermediate` to `result`.

Comment: @knot22, ah I see now

Comment: @knot22, I've updated the solution. You can take a look

Comment: This is a lot longer than my original logic which I'm trying to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

your approach was not bad. i built on it. the goal was to fill a global object. that was it.

```js
globalObj = {}
data = [
  { date: '10/1/2021', quantity: 47 },
  { date: '11/1/2021', quantity: 58 },
  { date: '12/1/2021', quantity: 96 },
  { date: '1/1/2022', quantity: 88 },
  { date: '2/1/2022', quantity: 90 },
];

data.forEach((o) => {
  [month, day, year] = o.date.split('/'); 
  
  if (!globalObj[year]) {
    globalObj[year] = { year }    
  }
    globalObj[year][month] = o.quantity    
})
const result = Object.values(globalObj)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct output.

Comment: @knot22 Thanks for the tip. I have corrected it.

Comment: This still does not produce the correct output.  `result` must be an array of objects.  This approach is not what I'm looking for anyhow.  The goal is to get `intermediate` to `result`.

Comment: I have added to it. it is too late today.